Maps of half-smash products (Lemma 4.32 in Strom's "Modern Classical Homotopy Theory").
[Cross-posted to MO]
For a pointed space $X$ and unpointed space $Y$, recall the half-smash product $X\rtimes Y=X\wedge Y_+=(X\times Y)/(\ast\times Y)$. In Jeffrey Strom's Modern Classical Homotopy Theory, there is a curious lemma (number 4.32) on maps between certain half-smash products. Namely, suppose $f\colon S^n\rtimes X\rightarrow S^n\rtimes Y$ is a pointed map between half-smash products and $d\colon S^n\rightarrow S^n$ a pointed map fitting in the commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
S^n\rtimes X @>{f}>> S^n\rtimes Y\\
@VVV @VVV\\
S^n @>{d}>> S^n
\end{CD}.$$
Here, the vertical maps are given by projection. The fiber of $S^n\rtimes X\rightarrow S^n$ over the basepoint is a point and over any other point is a copy of $X$. For $u\in S^n$ not the basepoint, Strom lets $\phi_u\colon X\rightarrow Y$ be the map induced on the fibers. He then fixes a quotient map $q\colon D^n\rightarrow S^n$ collapsing $S^{n-1}$ to the basepoint and claims the formula $H([q(u),x],t)=[dq(u),\phi_{(1-t)u}(x)]$ defines a homotopy between $f$ and $d\rtimes\phi_0$. (The notation is somewhat imprecise. There should be a $q$ in the index of the $\phi$-expressions.)
This is dubious to me. Namely, even if $u\in S^n$ is not the basepoint, it is possible that $d(u)\in S^n$ is. In this case, the map $\phi_u$ on the fiber does not really make sense (it is rather the constant map $X\rightarrow\ast$, but interpreting this as a constant map $X\rightarrow Y$ will not quite work). The "homotopy" $H$ is clearly through maps that fit into a commutative diagram as the above. Thus, if neither $q(u)$ nor $dq(u)$ are the basepoint, it restricts to a "homotopy" $X\times I\rightarrow Y,\,x\mapsto\phi_{q((1-t)u)}(x)$, so we better have joint coninuity among the $\phi$ and I don't see how to ensure that if $q((1-t)u)$ passes through a point of $S^n$ that is not the basepoint, but maps to the basepoint under $d$. So, is this lemma true (it better be, for it is central in Strom's derivation of the Serre spectral sequence) and, if so, how does one fix the gap in this proof?
Edit: In particular, Strom's sketch would imply that $\phi_u\simeq\phi_{q(0)}$ for all $u$ (at least when both are defined), but this cannot be as a simple example like
$$S^1\rtimes S^1\rightarrow S^1\rtimes S^1,\,z\rtimes w\mapsto\begin{cases}z^2\rtimes w,\,\mathrm{Im}(z)\ge0,\\z^2\rtimes\overline{w},\,\mathrm{Im}(z)\le 0\end{cases}$$
demonstrates. I'm not sure if this example invalidates the claim, but it seems to certainly invalidate the proof sketch.

Pointwise $H$ is well-defined:

If $q(u)$ is not base point, then $q((1-t)u)$ is not base point.
If $q(u)$ is base point, then $d(q(u))$ is base point and one does not need $q((1-t)u).$

Is the question about continuity of $H?$

Could you elaborate on $\phi_u\simeq\phi_{q(0)}?$ Explicitly stated only that $d\rtimes\phi_u\simeq d\rtimes\phi_{q(0)}.$

@dsh Yes, the question is about continuity, but I also am not sure of your point. The issue is that $d(q((1-t)u))$ can be the base point even if $q(u)$ is not. If the formula $(x,t)\mapsto\phi_{q((1-t)u)}(x)$ defines a homotopy, then $\phi_u\simeq\phi_{q(0)}$, so the failure of the latter condition indicates that this homotopy does not work.

From your arguments, it looks like issue with base points cannot be essentially avoided for map $d$ of degree not equal to $0, \pm1.$ Are you suggesting that one needs $d = d_1\vee \cdots\vee d_k$ in the case $d$ is of degree $\pm k$ and that $f\simeq d_1\rtimes \phi_{u_1}\vee \cdots\vee d_k\rtimes \phi_{u_k},$ where $d_i$ are $\pm1$-degree maps and $u_i$ are taken independently from components corresponding to $d_i?$ Or that one should restrict problem to maps of degree $\pm1?$

@dsh I don't have a suggestion. Note that the issue of a non-basepoint mapping to a basepoint can happen for maps of any degree and to a very uncontrollable extent.

I’m voting to close this question because it has been answered on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/478064/42153
